# Doubts about assertion in the test with mocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a test which uses a mocking framework (Mockito).

The SUT is a simple service class that on `get(String)` should ask repository (mock) to return - if exists - the Category object.

Since this is a unit test, you'll notice that I stub the `repository.findByName(String)` method to return an `Optional.of(category)`. I just want to test the service layer.

Here's the whole test case:

```
        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("com.demo.blog.postservice.category.CategoryServiceTest#categories")
        void shouldReturnCategory(Category category) {
            // arrange
            when(repository.findByName(category.getName())).thenReturn(Optional.of(category));

            // act
            Category actual = SUT.get(category.getName());

            // assert
            assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(category);
            verify(repository, times(1)).findByName(category.getName());
            verifyNoMoreInteractions(repository);
        }
```

The part that troubles me is the `assert` part. Note that I compare essentially the very same objects (references are equal), because `actual` is the mocked value from the `when(repository.findByName(category.getName())).thenReturn(Optional.of(category))`. This is bad.

How do I fix it in a nice way? I came up with this test case, although this smells a little: the way I create a new String disturbs me somehow.

```
        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("com.demo.blog.postservice.category.CategoryServiceTest#categories")
        void shouldReturnCategory(Category category) {
            // arrange
            String expectedName = new String(category.getName());
            when(repository.findByName(category)).thenReturn(Optional.of(category)));

            // act
            Category actual = SUT.get(category.getName());

            // assert
            PostAssertions.assertThat(actual).isNamed(expectedName);
            verify(repository, times(1)).findByName(category.getName());
            verifyNoMoreInteractions(repository);
        }
```

I'm open to any suggestions.

**UPDATE:**

- `category.getName()` returns a String
- The tested service method:

```
    Category get(String categoryName) {
        if(categoryName == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Category name was null");
        return categoryRepository.findByName(categoryName)
                .orElseThrow(CategoryNotFoundException::new);
    }
```

- Category class:

```
@Document("category")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Category {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String name;
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me category.getName() return type ? And please share Category class as well as service method.

Comment: @Az.MaYo Sure, I've updated the main post.

Comment: *"Note that I compare essentially the very same objects (references are equal),"* **--** No, you don't. You compare the name of the expected Category being a`String` with  the `Category` object returned by your service. They are not the same object nor equal by their `equals()` method.

Answer (score -2):

I have create simply created Junit and it's working fine

```
@Test
void testGetCategoryByName() {
    // Arrange
    String categoryName = "TestCategory";
    Category expectedCategory = new Category();
    expectedCategory.setName(categoryName);    
    when(categoryRepository.findByName(categoryName)).thenReturn(Optional.of(expectedCategory));

    // Act
    Category result = categoryService.get(categoryName);

    // Assert
    assertEquals(expectedCategory, result);
}

@Test
    void testGetCategoryByNameException() {
        // Arrange
        String categoryName = "TestCategory";
        when(categoryRepository.findByName(categoryName)).thenThrow(CustomException.class);
        assertThrows(CustomException.class, () -> categoryService.get(categoryName));
    }
```

Comment: I know the test is working. My JUnit case also did. The reason I created this post is because I feel like the practice I've implemented "code smells". I wanted the feedback on the implementation, not confirmation that it works.

Plus, it seems to me that your test is essentially the very same mistake I made in my first implementation that I've showed in the original post. You're comparing the same reference of `Category` objects which essentially comes down to `assertThat(true).isTrue()` which will always be... true.

Comment: No, it depends upon your logic, if you are not doing anything in the service then it's a simple code coverage, And 2nd thing please edit your service layer and there update the name of the category and then run test case again it will failed. Hopefully you will understand my point

Comment: @IceMajor "I wanted the feedback on the implementation,"* **--** Then you may ask this question in https://codereview.stackexchange.com again?